# Remove parts of a string and copy the rest back to a file with vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I would like to remove the unwanted text from each string in a file.
the input string looks like this

```
username^time stamp^don't need this printed on printer name more useless info pages printed:some number
```

I want to remove everything else but keep the username,time stamp,printer name and some number.Then write each line to a file so the output looks like this

```
username  timestamp printername some number
```

This is the code I'm working with

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sf = "C:\test.txt"
Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(sf, 1) ''1=for reading
s = f.ReadAll
segments = Split(s,"^",-1)
s= segments(1,)
f.Close
Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(sf, 2) ''2=ForWriting
f.Write s
f.Close
```

Comment: I don't understand your input format. Are all fields (necessary or not) separated by ^? If not, how can you cut the printer name from ... <other arbitrary junk>printer name<other arbitrary junk> ...

Comment: does this look any better     

username^time^(other arbitrary junk)^printer name^(other arbitrary junk)^ page count

So I need everything but the (other arbitrary junk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always a moment that somebody asks "Why not use a regular expression?". This is that moment.

Try this:

```
Dim re, s, match, matches

s = "Chuck Norris^12-12-2012^don't need this printed on HAL9000 more useless info pages printed:42  "

Set re = new regexp
re.pattern = "(.*)\^(.*)\^.*printed on (\w+).*pages printed:(\d+).*"
re.Global = True

Set matches = re.Execute(s)
Set match = matches(0)

msgbox "username=" & match.submatches(0)
msgbox "time stamp=" & match.submatches(1)
msgbox "printer=" & match.submatches(2)
msgbox "pages printed=" & match.submatches(3)
```

Neat huh? And I bet you'll figure out how to implement it in your existing code.

Comment: The script works. But there is a problem I need to preform the script on a file that has about 100,000 lines or so in it. I'm having trouble just getting it read 2 lines using a loop. Once I get it to work I think it will take to long to be effective

Comment: You can `split` the `f.ReadAll` on the `vbNewLine` character and use the regexp on each item in the array. Or you can use `ts.ReadLine` on the file opened as **TextStream** and process it line by line `Until ts.AtEndOfStream`.

Comment: The code works but the pattern doesn't seem to work with the real data
the real data looks like this
fl1^domainname\username^20120206162216.000000-300^Document 239, outbind://106-000000005315FCEA423BD111B0BA00609773F8F60700F5439 owned by username ^ printed on printer_HPCOLOR3600N via port npi702932.something.something.com  Size in bytes: 1711164; pages printed: 4
Could you possible come up with a new pattern that can cover this data set Thanks again

Comment: The regexp will be `.*\^(\w*\\\w*)\^([\d\.\-]*)\^.*printed on (\w+).*pages printed:.*(\d+).*` but it could be more optimized. And please, learn yourself the regex syntax. On the internet there are multiple sites where you can [learn](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) them and eventually [test](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html) them. Besides that: You **really** should be more precise in your requirements. The string you gave us was not very clear, and also in the last comment it's still not clear what you really want, resulting in extra work for everyone, including you.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
  Const csSep = "^"
                      'username^time^(other arbitrary junk)^printer name^(other arbitrary junk)^page count
  Dim sJunk  : sJunk  = "kurt^01:02:03^some junk^nec p7^nix^123"
  WScript.Echo sJunk
  Dim aParts : aParts = Split(sJunk, csSep)
  Dim sNetto : sNetto = Join(Array(aParts(0),aParts(1),aParts(3),aParts(5)), csSep)
  WScript.Echo sNetto
```

output:

```
kurt^01:02:03^some junk^nec p7^nix^123
kurt^01:02:03^nec p7^123
```